# Android style dosen't work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to add a specific style for a button, the issue is that it's works in themes.xml when I write this :

**themes.xml**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>
   </style>
```

**mylayout.xml**

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Play"
    android:textColor="@color/guillotine_background"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

but I don't get the same result when I use this :

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="MyColorButton" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/background</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I added this line to the button tag in mylayout.xml

**mylayout.xml**

```
  style="@style/MyColorButton"
```

Isn't that must return the same result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colorControlHighlight` and `colorButtonNormal` are theme attributes. They are for styles that are used as themes for an Activity. They are not attributes of a `Button`. If you want to use it on the `Button` but not the whole Activity, use `android:theme` attribute instead:

```
<Button
    android:theme="@style/MyColorButton"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

dmk you are doing it right , you just need to change the parent in the style of the button .
 just set the parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button" your code will work fine..

```
 <style name="appbutton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/themeColordark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

thanks